# Send Json data from listview in one activity to another activity

Tags: android, json, listview, android-intent

I am trying to send the json object data from one activity to other activity. I have a listview that is successfully populated from a json array, but as i click on a list item, it is not responding. No action is being performed on item click. I saw some tutorials but it did not helped. I need to send the list item's json data to another activity. Any help would be appreciated.

Activity of listview populated with Json.

```
       try{

         jArray = new JSONArray(result);
         ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listtour_cat);
         listView.setAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(JSONUseActivity.this,jArray));
         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    if(!jArray.isNull(arg2)){
                           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TourDetailActivity.class);  
                           intent.putExtra("id", jArray.optJSONObject(arg2).getString("tour_id"));
                           startActivity(intent);    
                     }

                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                       Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
               }

            }
        });
       }
       catch(JSONException e){
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
       }

  }
        catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
  }
```

Target Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String rcvid = intent.getStringExtra("id");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rcvid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: @Divyang-pls show your logcat error to understand the problem-

Comment: are u sure the onItemClick is not invoked? Or can you check whether you are getting any exceptions inside the onItemClick block?

Comment: @FarhaSameer786 - its not any error..its just not doing anything on clicking the list items.

Answer (score 1):

Convert JsonArray to String then attach it to Intent ans send it.

```
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject("Your Json Response");

    Intent obj_intent = new Intent(Main.this, Main1.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();                
    b.putString("Array",jObject4.toString());
    obj_intent.putExtras(b);
```

Where jObject4 is JSON Object.

Get in next Page :

```
        Intent b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String Array=b.getString("Array");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TourDetailActivity.class);  
intent.putExtra("id", jArray.getJSONObject(arg2).getString("tour_id"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code for getting value in second class..

```
String rcvid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id").toString();
```

And pass value from First class with intent like:

```
intent.putExtra("id", jArray.optJSONObject(arg2));
```